# How to strip directory structure with command line (or script)

Tags: shell, command-line, files, directory, rename

I have a large collection of files packed into a two-level directory structure with many, many, many folders.

In other words, I have a folder with a great many subfolders in it.  There are no subfolders in these subfolders, however, there are hundreds of files in them.

What I would like to do is move all the files out of these subfolders into the directory that holds the subfolders.

This is a limited resource system, so a way to do it without two copies of all these files having to exist at once would be amazing......

Comment: Can you please edit your post and give an approximated tree view of your current situation, and one of the desired "after"?

Comment: So it has been done...

Answer (score 1):

With GNU tools:

```
cd that-dir &&
  find . -mindepth 2 ! -type d -exec mv -it . {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the parent directory and run

```
mv -- */* .
```

(`--` is only necessary if there are subdirectories whose name begins with `-`)

If there are files in the subdirectories that begin with `.` (dot files), or subdirectories whose name begins with `.`, you'll need to move them as well:

```
mv -- */* */.[!.]* */..?* .
mv -- .[!.]*/* .[!.]*/.[!.]* .[!.]*/..?* .
mv -- ..?*/* ..?*/.[!.]* ..?*/..?* .
```

Make sure that there are no conflicts, otherwise the last file you move will silently overwrite a previously-moved file with the same name. Pass the `-i` option to `mv` (i.e. `mv -i */* .`) to be prompted in case of a conflict.

You can then remove the subdirectories:

```
rmdir */
```

If you get an error telling you that the command line is too long, you'll have to do it in several steps. The easy way is with the `find` command:

```
find */ -type f -exec mv -i {} . \;
```

or, slightly faster:

```
find */ -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -i -- "$@" "$0"' . {} +
```

Even faster, on a non-embedded Linux system:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -it . {} +
```